# How to lock certain columns from being edited for a user in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, security, locking, postgresql-9.3

How to lock **certain columns** from being edited even though user have access to editing rights for the table in postgresql.

Comment: The only secure way is to revoke the privilege to update those columns.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `GRANT`/`REVOKE`. But you could create a writable view with a different owner/rights, which could omit some columns and/or make some only read-able (with explicit `INSTEAD OF` triggers or rules).

Comment: or monkey hack with trigger - to return null instead of NEW

Comment: @pozs: Wouldn't `revoke update on some_table (column_one, column_two) from some_user` accomplish just that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe (with a slightly different syntax), but I assume GRANT would be active for the whole table, so I'm not sure yet (hold on). If the role is the owner, it certainly not enough though.

Comment: Revoking only column permissions will not affect updates if there is separate table grant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in my tests if a whole table has `update` right granted, but some of its column's `update` right is revoked, than the role still can update those columns too (in 9.6). Maybe I'm missing a point here, because column specific rights doesn't seem that helpful this way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but, it seems to be working in the other way around: `revoke update on some_table from some_user; grant update (col1, col3, col4) on some_table to user;` But OP needs to specify all of the write-able columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a trigger that barfs if a forbidden column gets changed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cerberus() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF NEW.forbiddencol IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.forbiddencol
      AND current_user = 'luser'
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '"luser" must not update "forbiddencol"';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER cerberus BEFORE UPDATE OF mytable
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cerberus();
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample snippets?

Comment: I have added a sample.

Comment: This will not prevent update if old or new is null, since `select case when 1 <> null then true else false end` will return `false`.

Comment: Is there any way to catch update like this and raise exception?If so can you please edit your answer?

Comment: Hmpf. I was just giving an example, not writing your code for you. The obvious solution is to use `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Answer (score 9):

PostgreSQL supports Column Security (as well as Row Security)

Let's call our limited role `authors`

```
create table staff (
  name text primary key,
  salary decimal(19,4)
);

create role authors;

grant select, insert, delete, update(name) on table staff to authors;

set role authors;

insert into staff values ('frank', 100); -- works!

select * from staff; -- works!

update staff set name='jim'; -- works!

update staff set salary=999; -- permission denied
```